# FormDataPart String wrong charset

Tags: jersey

I'm stuck with this problem for two days now. The jersey verion is 2.6.

I have enabled the logging of the request by adding a loggingfilter. Which works well.
My rerquest is logged using the right charset:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="verskomm"
kleine Änderung
```

Wenn I want to consume this request using @FormDataParam I get

```
kleine ?nderung
```

Where can I set the charset which should be used to decode these parts of the request?

I have no influence on the request, as it is made by a third party program.